# Tensor value changes when evaluated multiple times

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to do data augmentation on a small batch of images of batch size 4.(Just for testing purpose)

```
sess = tf.Session()
#Create dataset
dataset = get_dataset()
#Set seed placeholder
seedin = tf.placeholder(tf.int64,shape=())
#Get iterator
iterator = create_next_batch_iterator(dataset,seedin)
#Initialize the Iterator
sess.run(iterator.initializer,feed_dict={seedin:6})
#Get next batch
next_batch = get_next_batch(iterator)
print next_batch
print 'without augmentation:',next_batch['labels'].eval(session=sess)
```

The output I am getting is

```
{'images': <tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:0' shape=(4, 96, 96, 3) dtype=uint8>, 
'labels': <tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:1' shape=(4,) dtype=uint8>}
without augmentation: [6 1 7 6]
```

But If I replace the last line with the next line of code

```
next_batch = augment_data(get_next_batch(iterator),sess)
print next_batch
```

The **problem** starts here...

Code for the `augment_data` function

```
def augment_data(batch,sess,naug=5):
    labels_tensor = batch['labels'].eval(session=sess)
    print labels_tensor
    labels_array = np.array(batch['labels'].eval(session=sess))
    print labels_array
```

I get two different values for `labels_tensor` and `labels_array`

```
[6 1 7 6]
[9 3 8 4]
```

These values are the same values I get if I execute

```
next_batch = get_next_batch(iterator)
print next_batch
```

two consecutive times.

It seems, that whenever I am trying to get the Tensors from `batch`, the `get_next_batch()` function is getting executed, and that's why I am getting a new set of values.

Why is that??
How can I solve this problem?

Comment: These tensors are results of a tree of operations.  All parent operations in the tree - e.g. `get_next_batch` - are executed when evaluating the tensor.  You better hold on to the result of eval.

Comment: How can I do that @Jus ? I am now trying to do `next_batch_labels = tf.Variable(next_batch['labels'])`. Assigning a variable for the labels and then run `eval()`

Comment: So, is it that in the first piece of code `next_batch['labels'].eval(session=sess)` does not return the same value, as that stored in `next_batch = get_next_batch(iterator)`?? @Jus

Comment: Nothing is stored at that point (except the initialization).  It's only a computational graph.  Calling Eval creates the value.

Comment: Okay, now I get it. In the function even if I pass the `next_batch` as argument, the graph still gets evaluated from the top, every time I call `eval()` inside the function. But not in the first case because it is just storing the tensor in `next_batch` which is getting evaluated when I call `next_batch['labels'].eval(session=sess)`